# Where are docs about Game Constants?

Tags: javascript, screeps

In the tutorial I'm seeing: Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS

```
var targets = creep.room.find(Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS);
```

No where in the docs do I see anything that tells me this is possible. Where would I find out more about these constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documents got updated, check below [Game.php#notify](http://screeps.com/docs/Game.php#notify) in the docs. As of posting these are the constants:

**Result codes**

```
Game.OK 0
Game.ERR_NOT_OWNER  -1
Game.ERR_NO_PATH    -2
Game.ERR_NAME_EXISTS    -3
Game.ERR_BUSY   -4
Game.ERR_NOT_FOUND  -5
Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_ENERGY  -6
Game.ERR_INVALID_TARGET -7
Game.ERR_FULL   -8
Game.ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE   -9
Game.ERR_INVALID_ARGS   -10
Game.ERR_TIRED  -11
Game.ERR_NO_BODYPART    -12
Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_EXTENSIONS  -13
```

**Room.find() constants**

```
Game.CREEPS 1
Game.MY_CREEPS  2
Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS 3
Game.SOURCES_ACTIVE 4
Game.SOURCES    5
Game.DROPPED_ENERGY 6
Game.STRUCTURES 7
Game.MY_STRUCTURES  8
Game.HOSTILE_STRUCTURES 9
Game.FLAGS  10
Game.CONSTRUCTION_SITES 11
Game.MY_SPAWNS  12
Game.HOSTILE_SPAWNS 13
Game.EXIT_TOP   14
Game.EXIT_RIGHT 15
Game.EXIT_BOTTOM    16
Game.EXIT_LEFT  17
```

**Direction constants**

```
Game.TOP    1
Game.TOP_RIGHT  2
Game.RIGHT  3
Game.BOTTOM_RIGHT   4
Game.BOTTOM 5
Game.BOTTOM_LEFT    6
Game.LEFT   7
Game.TOP_LEFT   8
```

**Body parts**

```
Game.MOVE   "move"
Game.WORK   "work"
Game.CARRY  "carry"
Game.ATTACK "attack"
Game.RANGED_ATTACK  "ranged_attack"
Game.TOUGH  "tough"
Game.HEAL   "heal"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the docs: http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#find

You'll see a little button with three dots in it, click it and it will show the list of constants.  A lot of the functions have this additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Try the doc for the find(...) function on the page for [room](http://www.screeps.com/docs/Room.php#find)

I would say those are pretty self explanatory

Comment: If you're looking for a parameter for the `room.find()` method, you should check this method's documentation